# Dashed UIBezierPath subpath junctions

Tags: swift, uibezierpath

I create dashed UIBezierPath using some passed points.

```
let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
pathLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
pathLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
pathLayer.lineDashPattern = [5.0, 2.0]
pathLayer.lineDashPhase = 0

let path = PathCreator.createPath(resultPoints)

pathLayer.path = path.cgPath
```

I've simplified PathCreator, but totally it looks something like this

```
PathCreator {
    func createPath(resultPoints: [CGPoint]) -> UIBezierPath {
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        for i in 0..<(resultPoints.count-1) {
            if resultPoints[i] is CircleCenterPoint {
                continue
            }
            if resultPoints[i] is ArcEndPoint {
                path.move(to: resultPoints[i].cg())
                path.addLine(to: resultPoints[i+1].cg())
            }
            if let arcStartPoint = resultPoints[i] as? ArcStartPoint,
               let circleCenterPoint = resultPoints[i+1] as? CircleCenterPoint,
               let arcEndPoint = resultPoints[i+2] as? ArcEndPoint {
                path.addArc(withCenter: circleCenterPoint.cg(),
                radius: circleCenterPoint.radius,
                startAngle: arcStartPoint.arcStartAngle,
                endAngle: arcEndPoint.arcEndAngle,
                clockwise: circleCenterPoint.clockwise)
            } else {
                path.move(to: resultPoints[i].cg())
                path.addLine(to: resultPoints[i+1].cg())
            }
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

But sometimes i have problems at the junction of subpaths:

[image: path example]

What am i missing?

Comment: Are the extra long dashes just a combination of the end of one path and the beginning of the next? If so, make sure to add an extra empty space at the end of each path in the loop. I'm not sure thats the issue but I'd be my guess by just glancing at the picture.

Comment: yes, this is the problem. But if i add extra space, then i will need to recalculate points origins, and i believe that it is not the true way)

Comment: maybe there is a way to tell ios to draw all this route as one single path? So, ios will calculate dashes as i need

Comment: what is the direction of the path?

Comment: starts at the top

Comment: Use 'path.move' for only the 1st element of resultPoints. For rest elements of reulstPoints, use 'path.addLine'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't follow this question for a long time. But now, when I came back, I found that I actually changed my code and it seems to work quite good. Here is the code that can be posted into playground and tested. Also this code doesn't expect any special types for points and other helper things. Check it out :)

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class PathCreator {
    func createPath(by points: [CGPoint]) -> CGPath {
        let path = CGMutablePath()
        if points.count >= 3 {
            path.move(to: points.first!)
            for i in 0..<(points.count - 2) {
                let startPoint = points[i]
                let middlePoint = points[i+1]
                let endPoint = points[i+2]

                let isOnOneLin = isOnOneLine(point1: startPoint, point2: middlePoint, point3: endPoint)
                if isOnOneLin {
                    path.addLine(to: middlePoint)
                    if i == points.count - 3 {
                        path.addLine(to: endPoint)
                        break
                    }

                } else {
                    let currentAngleValue = angleBetween(vector1: (startPoint, middlePoint), vector2: (middlePoint, endPoint))
                    print(currentAngleValue)
                    if currentAngleValue < 45 {
                        path.addArc(tangent1End: middlePoint, tangent2End: endPoint, radius: 1)
                    } else {
                        path.addArc(tangent1End: middlePoint, tangent2End: endPoint, radius: 10)
                    }
                    if i == points.count - 3 {
                        path.addLine(to: endPoint)
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if points.count == 2 {
            path.move(to: points.first!)
            path.addLine(to: points[1])
        }

        return path
    }

    private func angleBetween(vector1: (CGPoint, CGPoint), vector2: (CGPoint, CGPoint)) -> CGFloat {

        //  vector1.0
        //     ^
        //     \
        //      \
        //       \
        //        \
        //         ---------->vector2.1
        //     vector1.1
        //     vector2.0

        let dx1 = vector1.0.x - vector1.1.x
        let dy1 = vector1.0.y - vector1.1.y
        let vector1 = CGVector(dx: dx1, dy: dy1)

        let dx2 = vector2.1.x - vector2.0.x
        let dy2 = vector2.1.y - vector2.0.y
        let vector2 = CGVector(dx: dx2, dy: dy2)

        let scalarProduct = vector1.dx * vector2.dx + vector1.dy * vector2.dy

        let vector1Module = sqrt(vector1.dx * vector1.dx + vector1.dy * vector1.dy)
        let vector2Module = sqrt(vector2.dx * vector2.dx + vector2.dy * vector2.dy)

        let result = acos(scalarProduct / (vector1Module * vector2Module))
        return result * 180 / .pi
    }

    private func isOnOneLine(point1: CGPoint, point2: CGPoint, point3: CGPoint) -> Bool {
        let x1 = point1.x
        let x2 = point2.x
        let x3 = point3.x
        let y1 = point1.y
        let y2 = point2.y
        let y3 = point3.y
        let a = (x1 - x3) * (y2 - y3)
        let b = (x2 - x3) * (y1 - y3)
        let area = 1 / 2 * (a - b)
        if area != 0 {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
}




let str = "hello"

let points = [CGPoint(x: 150, y: 150),
              CGPoint(x: 350, y: 150),
              CGPoint(x: 350, y: 350),
              CGPoint(x: 550, y: 350),
              CGPoint(x: 550, y: 450),
              CGPoint(x: 205, y: 455),
              CGPoint(x: 450, y: 650),
              CGPoint(x: 185, y: 750)]

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1000, height: 1000))
view.backgroundColor = .white
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view

let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
pathLayer.lineWidth = 4.0
pathLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
pathLayer.lineDashPattern = [5.0, 2.0]
pathLayer.lineDashPhase = 0

view.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer)

let pathCreator = PathCreator()
let path = pathCreator.createPath(by: points)
pathLayer.path = path
```

And the result is on the image:

[image]

Although the solution is probably not perfect. I think it can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'path.move' only for the 1st point. For the rest of points, use 'path.addLine'.

So solution will be something like below:

```
PathCreator {
    func createPath(resultPoints: [CGPoint]) -> UIBezierPath {
        var wMoved = false;
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        for i in 0..<(resultPoints.count-1) {
            if resultPoints[i] is CircleCenterPoint {
                continue
            }
            if resultPoints[i] is ArcEndPoint {
                if wMoved {
                    path.addLine(to: resultPoints[i].cg())
                } else {
                    path.move(to: resultPoints[i].cg())
                    wMoved = true
                }
                path.addLine(to: resultPoints[i+1].cg())
            }
            if let arcStartPoint = resultPoints[i] as? ArcStartPoint,
               let circleCenterPoint = resultPoints[i+1] as? CircleCenterPoint,
               let arcEndPoint = resultPoints[i+2] as? ArcEndPoint {
                path.addArc(withCenter: circleCenterPoint.cg(),
                radius: circleCenterPoint.radius,
                startAngle: arcStartPoint.arcStartAngle,
                endAngle: arcEndPoint.arcEndAngle,
                clockwise: circleCenterPoint.clockwise)
            } else {
                if wMoved {
                    path.addLine(to: resultPoints[i].cg())
                } else {
                    path.move(to: resultPoints[i].cg())
                    wMoved = true
                }
                path.addLine(to: resultPoints[i+1].cg())
            }
        }
        return path
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like your answer should do the right thing. I will try to check it, but for this I need to find my old project and test inside. Then accept I will accept your answer, if everything is fine :)

Comment: Well, I downloaded that project, but I found that actually it looks like I fixed this problem another way. Will post here my solution also :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your CAShapeLayer is a single path, justset the lineJoin property for the path. In your case I think a kCALineJoinRound would work. [Possible line join values.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/cashapelayer/1667691-line_join_values)

```
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound
```

Comment: nothing has changed :(
maybe there is a way to tell ios to draw all this route as one single path?

Comment: That's how it works for me - draw a single path (yeah, mines a rectangle), turn it into a CAShapeLayer, define the dash pattern along with the lineJoin. The only difference I can see from my code to yours' is I do a closePath().

Comment: close() adds more strange lines :) because documentation says: "This method closes the current subpath by creating a line segment between the first and last points in the subpath. This method subsequently updates the current point to the end of the newly created line segment, which is also the first point in the now closed subpath."